# At times number display in cart icon showing null only in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, header, zend-framework2

Hello I'm working on Zend Framework 2. In which we have a Module.php where I've written a common function to fetch the Count of Cart items. Everytime page refreshes / Loaded. The item count fetched from DB & shown next to the Cart Icon. This works well in Chrome & FireFox. But, when it comes to IE (internet Explorer) shows me the hell, at time shows as Zero (even though added couple of items to cart) with cart items empty in the view cart page.
This happens only in IE all versions. Please suggest me what should I have to do to work fine in all IE versions.

In Module / Application /Module.php
Sample code

```
<pre>
//under bootstrap function :
//Setting the variable to view page as 



     function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
            $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('cartCount', $cartCount);
        }

</pre>
```

Here the $cartCount value is fetched through the Query with session Id as I/P value to the query.

Please suggest me what should I'v to do for making working well in IE all versions..

Thanks in-advance,
Srinivasu

Comment: This can't be a typical error in ZF2. Just start debugging, as I have no idea what you mean with "Here the $cartCount value is fetched through the Query with session Id as I/P value to the query." 1) check the query 2) check the session id.

Comment: Hi Mr.Jurian, I have written SQL query to fetch the $cartCount value ( number of items in cart - That's been stored in the DB ) in Module.php file. "SELECT count(cartItems) as cartCount FROM cart-info WHERE refId = SessionID" At times it shows the number & at times it wont.So, is that something missing in reading Session Value (SessionId)?

Comment: This can be a bug die to session collisions. There is a similar bug in Magento where one user end with the session of another user.... Also PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE don't put such code in Module.php as the whole Module.php code is executed on EVERY request and after some time you will end with big performance issues.

Chec your sessions from the dev tools of IE

Answer (score 0):

Check your privacy settings in internet options -> privacy tab. Look out if you have disabled cookies or something.

Are you able to login and add "multiple" items in cart?